# Find a string in scanned images in C#.net

Tags: c#, pdf

I want a C# program that searches a string in a PDF file which contains only the scanned images. Also, the code should display that particular page in which the searched string is present.

For example, Consider a PDF file that contains scanned images(.png) of Receipts. I want to search for a receipt_number. Then the page in which that particular receipt_number is present, should be open up in the PDF reader.

I would like to use MODI for this.

Comment: Have you tried something for this?

Comment: This site is not here to make people work for you. Please explain what you have tried and where you failed. If you have tried nothing, then start by [searching the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Microsoft+Office+Document+Imaging+c%23) for examples.

Comment: Since I am a newbie to the industry and .NET platform, I don't know how to code it but I don't expect full code. I am asking you about the idea or any hint to achieve my task. I have searched web and I got results either for extracting images or for finding a text from the PDF file.But I need both. Please suggest me any idea you have even it is not MODI. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's actually a pretty complicated task.  I have tried something similar before and the results are not always great; however, the program I created, and currently have, does what I need it to do well enough.  The reason it worked well for me is due to the fact that I focused on a very specific area of the page, where I knew I would find specifically-formatted text.  Mind you, that only worked well for printed text... stamped or hand-written text was a pain to deal with.  With enough OCR training, I'm sure that could be fixed, but I didn't have have additional time to devote to that project.

Your results will heavily depend on the OCR method you choose, scan quality, whether it's typed or written by hand, whether the scan is perfectly aligned or slightly skewed, etc., etc., etc.

I'm not going to give you any code, as you won't learn anything if I do, but I'll give you a few tips of how to get started. If you get stuck, post a specific question here and hopefully you'll get some help.

There are many ways and the way I've tried is through conversion of the scanned PDF file into images (one per page).  Then, I ran the images through a recognition algorithm in attempt to retrieve all of the text (in my case, it was a specific rectangle on the image).

So, to get images out a PDF, you can use something like Magick.NET.  It's even available through NuGet, so that should be an easy part.  Since it's a scanned PDF, you should not have any issues getting the images out.  There are plenty of tutorials and if you get stuck post a specific question on this site.

The optical character recognition part is the hard part; however, there are some libraries that may assist you or, at the very least, get you started.  I used the tessnet2 library (http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/).

There are some C# wrappers available and you may even be able to find something from NuGet.   Here's one place on GitHub (https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract).  Also, have a look here: https://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/ and here: https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-ocr-dotnet.

Some of those are for tessnet3 and some are for tessnet2.  I've had success with tessnet2 32-bit version, but not the others.  So, give all of them a go and see what works for you,

Know ahead of time that you're diving into a pretty complicated area and that if you get stuck or fail to understand certain things, don't get frustrated... give it time.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion B.K. I will try it.